# How do I undo a 'set arabic' command in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm a vim noob who was doing a little exploring. In the terminal I ran `:set arabic` just out of curiosity.

I ended up with all my code right-justified and flipped backwards (i.e. `import` became `tropmi`).

I understand that exiting Vim and restarting will undo those changes. I am just interested in knowing what command would reverse those changes without me having to close and open Vim.

Comment: try, set:english ??

Comment: Might want to ask this on [vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Read `:help arabic`

Comment: Close voters: I disagree this is off topic as vim is definitely among the ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the proper incantation is `:set noarabic`. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/arabic.html

Comment: You can unset boolean flags by doing :set no[setting]

Answer (score 2):

`:set noarabic`

All the Boolean flags can be turned off by prefixing `no`.

Further, since you are new to Vim:

1. You can get status of flag using `?`: `:set arabic?`
2. Toggle the flag using `!`: `set arabic!`

Comment: Or `set invarabic`